# How Broken Is the Broken Printer (Javascript Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

### Task

> In a factory a printer prints labels for boxes. For one kind of boxes
>   the printer has to use colors which, for the sake of simplicity, are
>   named with letters from a to m.
>
> The colors used by the printer are recorded in a control string. For
>   example a "good" control string would be aaabbbbhaijjjm meaning that
>   the printer used three times color a, four times color b, one time
>   color h then one time color a...
>
> Sometimes there are problems: lack of colors, technical malfunction
>   and a "bad" control string is produced e.g. aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm
>   with letters not from a to m.
>
> You have to write a function printer_error which given a string will
>   output the error rate of the printer as a string representing a
>   rational whose numerator is the number of errors and the denominator
>   the length of the control string. Don't reduce this fraction to a
>   simpler expression.
>
> The string has a length greater or equal to one and contains only
>   letters from ato z.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> ```
> s="aaabbbbhaijjjm"
> error_printer(s) => "0/14"
>
> s="aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm"
> error_printer(s) => "8/22"
> ```

### My Attempt

Ok I am super sorry for the long code (it could probably be a lot shorter):

```js
function printerError(s){
  let regex = /[a-m]/g
  let winCount = 0;
  let totalCount = 0;
  s.split('').map((item)=>{
    totalCount++;
    if(regex.test(item)){
      winCount++;
    }
  })
  let a = winCount / totalCount;
  
  let b = (decimal) => {
  for(var denominator = 1; (decimal * denominator) % 1 !== 0; denominator++);
  return {numerator: decimal * denominator, denominator: denominator};

  }

 let c = b(a);
let d = Object.values(c);
let e = d.toString();
let regex2 = /,/;
let f = e.replace(regex2, '/');
return f;

};



console.log(printerError('adfsdgdsrwe'));
```

### My Question

The engineer is broken. Please help me find the error that is causing the output to be way off!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582826/as-a-newbie-i-cant-find-the-bug-in-the-program https://blog.onewayfirst.com/algorithms/posts/2019-09-05-codewar-7kyu-1/

Comment: appreciated, although my hope is to understand what I did wrong specifically :)

Comment: I don't know if I understood it very well .. You want to create a function that returns the error quotient about the total length of the string, is that it?

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp Everything looks good until the line `let a = winCount / totalCount;`. Can you explain what you tried to do after that?

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp Notice in particular "*a rational whose numerator is the number of errors and the denominator the length of the control string. Don't reduce this fraction to a simpler expression.*" All you have to do is `return errorCount + '/' + totalCount;`

Comment: If that's what I understood, I could have written it this way:

Comment: @edit I will put it in codepen, here it is not well identified: https://codepen.io/aks-jacoves/pen/yLeOdLj?editors=1111

Comment: @Bergi after winCout / totalCount I converted the decimal to a fraction (the values of the object were the numerator and the denominator). Then I iterated through the values and converted to an array. Then I made it a string and replaced the ',' with a '/'

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp Ah. Hm, you just never should've created a decimal at all :-) Also this *does* simplify the fraction (e.g. `0.5` => `1/2`, even if it should've been `2/4` or `3/6` or so). And notice that you should never use `Object.values` or go via an array at all, as it does not guarantee the order of property values. To create the string from the fraction object, you should've written just `const f = c.numerator + '/' + c.denominator;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned in the comments, you misunderstood the task and let yourself be confused by the denominator stuff. That way it's hard to 'fix' your code. You only need to identify the number of wrong letters and the length of the string. The idea using a regex was nice. I would suggest you do it the other way around and count the number of mismatching letters.

```js
let error_printer = (s) => {
  // Count all matches, which match the regexp which is looking for letters, 
  // which are NOT within a-m. If no are found, just use 0.
  // Then append / with the length of the string.
  return (s.match(/[^a-m]/g)?.length || 0) + "/" + s.length;
}

let s="aaabbbbhaijjjm"
console.log(error_printer(s)) // => "0/14"

s="aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm"
console.log(error_printer(s)); // => "8/22"
```

EDIT: I've just seen that @Aks Jacoves did a quite similar approach in the comments using codepen.